# Subset of values with length>=N and sum>=S

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a list of values (e.g. 10, 15, 20, 30, 70), values N (e.g. 3) and S (e.g. 100), find a subset that satisfies :

1. length of subset >= N
2. sum of subset >= S

The sum of the subset should also be the least possible (the sum of remaining values should be  the greatest possible) (e.g. result subset should be (10,20,70), not (15,20,70) which also satisfies 1. and 2.).

I was looking at some problems and solutions (Knapsack problem, Bin packing problem, ...) but didn't find them applicable. Similar problems on the internet were also not suitable for some reason (e.g. number of elements in subset was fixed).

Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there any other solution other than exhausting every possible combination?

Edit - working algorithm I implemented in ruby code, I guess it can be further optimized:

```
def find_subset_with_sum_and_length_threshold(vals, min_nr, min_sum)
    sum_map = {}
    vals.sort.each do |v|
      sum_map.keys.sort.each do |k|
        addends = sum_map[k] + [v]
        if (addends.length >= min_nr && k+v >= min_sum)
          return addends
        else
          sum_map[k+v] = addends
        end
      end
      sum_map[v] = [v] if sum_map[v].nil?
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very different from the 0-1 knapsack problem.

```
Zero-initialize a matrix with S+U rows and N columns(U is the largest list value)
Zero-initialize a bit array A with S+U elements
For each value (v) in the list:
  For each j<S:
    If M[N-1,j] != 0 and M[N-1, j + v] == 0:
      M[N-1, j + v] = v
      A[j + v] = true
  For i=N-2 .. 0:
    For each j<S:
      If M[i,j] != 0 and M[i+1, j + v] == 0:
        M[i+1, j + v] = v
  M[0,v] = v
Find first nonzero element in M[N-1,S..S+U]
Reconstruct other elements of the subset by subtracting found value from its\
  index and using the result as index in preceding column of the matrix\
  (or in the last column, depending on the corresponding bit in 'A').
```

Time complexity is O(L*N*S), where L is the length of the list, N and S are given limits.

Space complexity is O(L*N).

---

```
Zero-initialize an integer array A with S+U elements
i=0
For each value (v) in the list:
  For each j<S:
    If A[j] != 0 and A[j + v] < A[j] + 1:
      A[j + v] = A[j] + 1
      V[i,j + v] = v
      P[i,j + v] = I[j]
      I[j + v] = i
  If A[v] == 0:
    A[v] = 1
    I[v] = i
  ++i
Find first element in A[S..S+U] with value not less than N
Reconstruct elements of the subset using matrices V and P.
```

Time complexity is O(L*S), where L is the length of the list, S is given limit.

Space complexity is O(L*S).

---

Algorithm that also minimizes the subset size:

```
Zero-initialize a boolean matrix with S+U rows and N columns\
  (U is the largest list value)
Zero-initialize an integer array A with S+U elements
i=0
For each value (v) in the list:
  For each j<S:
    If A[j] != 0 and (A[j + v] == 0) || (A[j + v] > A[j] + 1)):
      A[j + v] = A[j] + 1
      V[i,N-1,j + v] = v
      P[i,N-1,j + v] = (I[j,N-1],N-1)
      I[j+v,N-1] = i
  For k=N-2 .. 0:
    For each j<S:
      If M[k,j] and not M[k+1, j + v]:
        M[k+1, j + v] = true
        V[i,k+1,j + v] = v
        P[i,k+1,j + v] = (I[j,k],k)
        I[j+v,k+1] = i
  For each j<S:
    If M[N-1, j]:
      A[j] = N-1
  M[0,v] = true
  I[v,0] = i
  ++i
Find first nonzero element in A[N-1,S..S+U] (or the first element with smallest\
  value or any other element that suits both minimization criteria)
Reconstruct elements of the subset using matrices V and P.
```

Time complexity is O(L*N*S), where L is the length of the list, N and S are given limits.

Space complexity is O(L*N*S).

Comment: If I am correct, with the first solution you are essentially building a matrix of sums of all subsets with a length <= N (hence the N columns). But then what if the solution subset required more elements than N? E.g. N=3,S=130, vals (10, 15, 20, 30, 70) => solution is (70,30,20,10)? Will look into the second solution.

Comment: What concerns me about the second solution is possible clashes (e.g. first A[j+v] is set to 3 and then it is possible that another v sets A[j+v] again to another value, e.g. 2. If this A[j+v] was the first element in A[S..S+U] in the end we would not find the first solution because it was written over later in the values loop).
But I see what your solutions are aiming at - building matrices and arrays of sums and then working out which combination produced the sum closest to S. I was thinking similarly.

Comment: @MatkoMedenjak: (first solution) if the solution subset requires more elements than N, all the remaining elements after N are accumulated in the last column (column0->10,column1->20, column2->30 and 70). It was a bug in the initial version of the answer. Now it is fixed.

Comment: @MatkoMedenjak: (second solution) after A[j+v] is set to some value (3) it may be overwritten only by larger value (4+). This may overwrite the first solution with other one which still obeys all the constraints. Unlike the first algorithm, this one, instead of the first found subset, produces the largest subset.

Comment: @MatkoMedenjak: by the way, there is a contradiction in OP. Question name requires minimizing the subset size while question body does not require it. My both algorithms do not minimize this size. But if you need this, take the first algorithm with the matrix of booleans and instead of last column use integer array (containing current subset size) which should be overwritten only by smaller values. And to reconstruct the resulting subset, use value/parent matrices as in the second algorithm.

Comment: The question body is relevant. Fixed the question name but I still don't know if it fits the body description.

Comment: @MatkoMedenjak: It still doesn't fit. Name requires "minimal number of elements" while body doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight variation of [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). Look at section `Pseudo-polynomial time dynamic programming solution`. In addition to keeping track whether a particular sum is possible (i.e. storing true/false) from the given set, you would need to store the length too to satisfy:

1. length of subset >= N

if `sum of subset = S` then it is exactly similar to the above problem. For `sum of subset >= S` condition, I guess you can test this condition when building the array as mentioned in the Wiki page.